# How to rename pd.Series duplicated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Pandas Series where I find duplicates values and I am trying to replace/rename these duplicate values with a value_integer. For example:

1. I am using a custom function to find duplicates in series

   def find_duplicates(self,data, key):
   return result

returns series of all duplicates in Series.

2. now I'm passing this function to another function where I want these values to be renamed/replace duplicates with _2,_3,_4 ....

   def rename_duplicates(self,data=None,key=None):
   count = 1
   duplicates = self.find_duplicates(data,key)

   ```
        return data
   ```

duplicated_values

apple
apple
apple
banana
banana
orange
orange

and I want to get

duplicated_values

```
apple_2
apple_3
apple_4
banana_2
banana_3
orange_2
orange_3
```

3. and then put it back to the original data frame

Answer (score 1):

Try with `cumcount`

```
df['new'] = df['yourcol'] + '_' +df.groupby('yourcol').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Comment: thank you, I've had something similar you sugested    data[key] = data[key] + data.groupby([key]).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0','_2')  , and I tried yours snipet , but it return only the duplicates without the _2,_3